# What's the correct way to handle command line arguments in Perl script?

Tags: perl, parsing, scripting, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to create a script/application which accepts command line arguments when run. Of course, this is a day-to-day thing, but seeing as this is the first time I'm doing it, I'm looking for some guidance. Let's say my script can take these kinds of command line arguments:

```
script -a -p /path/to/pipe -l mail.Error -m root@email.com
script -a -l mail.Error -m root@email.com -p /path/to/pipe

and so on....
```

Due to the flexible nature of command line scripts, the arguments you can pass to it can some in a variety of orders and could be missing/have invalid arguments. Now, I know this can be solved by being very strict about how the arguments must show up (first `-a`, then `-p` with a path, then `-l` with a log facility/priority and finally `-m` with a valid email) and by testing all possible occurrences of them.

But there has to be a better way. This is incredibly inefficient (to me) and I was wondering if there was a better way of doing things. I want to remain as flexible as possible and just make things work instead of focusing on strict usage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use [Getopt::Long](http://search.cpan.org/~jv/Getopt-Long/lib/Getopt/Long.pm) for arguments.

Untested example:

```
use Getopt::Long;
## set defaults
my $path   = '/tmp';
my $log = 'm.Error';
my $email = 'test@email.com';
my $a = 0;
my $result = GetOptions ("path=s"  => \$path,
                         "log=s"   => \$log,
                         "a"       => \$a,
                         "email=s" => \$email);
## both script -a -p /path/to/pipe -l mail.Error -m root@email.com
## and script -a -l mail.Error -m root@email.com -p /path/to/pipe
## should work now
```

Comment: You can also pass `GetOptions` a hash reference, and it will store all the information to the hash.  For example, given `GetOptions(\%opt, "path=s", "log=s")` passing `-path /tmp` will give you `$opt{path} == "/tmp"`.  I find it convenient to have information from command-line options easily visible in the code.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Getopt::Std` if you only want 1-character options, `Getopt::Long` if you want to support longer argument names.

Comment: Just always use `Getopt::Long` — it can handle both.

Comment: Yes, but `Getopt::Std` makes bundling a bit more straightforward, for example treating `-abc` as `-a -b -c` (at the expense of not handing long options at all).  Personally, I don't use bundling, and I haven't used `Getopt::Std` in years.  For the gory details, `perldoc Getopt::Long` and read the "Bundling" section (there are several configuration options).

Answer (score 0):

[Getopt::Long](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html) can automatically parse your command line into a hash variable.  The order on the command line does not matter.  You can check if options are given or not by checking hash keys.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Getopt::Long;

my %opts;
GetOptions(\%opts, qw(a p=s l=s m=s)) or die;
```